# Error with my syntax. Parsing Json/For-loop

Tags: json, python-2.7, parsing, for-loop, syntax

I'm trying to loop through a json response, saving all "video_urls". If I use this code, I can guarantee a link from the FIRST post, obviously.

```
pictureUrl = jsonResponse['response']['posts'][1]['video_url']
```

So I'm trying to turn this into a for loop to grab ALL video_urls from EVERYPOST not just [1] and it just isn't working... It's probably a super obvious answer but I'm confused.

```
    posts = jsonResponse.get('response', {}).get('posts', {})
    for post in posts:
        pictureUrl = jsonResponse['video_url']
```

That's the current section that isn't working... It has to be a super obvious syntax error that I'm not getting.

If someone can point me in the right direction to learn how to solve this, please let me know.

SOLVED:

```
    posts = jsonResponse.get('response', {}).get('posts', '')
    for post in posts:
        if ('video_url' in post):
            pictureUrl = post['video_url']
```

Comment: `pictureUrl = post['video_url'];`, probably. you're referring back to the toplevel json object, while rummaging around in its basement.

Comment: Tried that suggestion, still not working. I'm so lost.

Comment: then start basic debugging: dump out the contents of `post` inside the `for` loop so you can see what you're dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you define the current item in the iteration as `post`, but within the for loop, you reference `jsonResponse` instead.

To fix this, you'll want to update your code to the following:

```
posts = jsonResponse.get('response', {}).get('posts', {})
for post in posts:
    pictureUrl = post['video_url']
```